# Modify Gmail (IMAP/SMTP) settings in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, imap

I have Outlook configured to access a gmail account.  Recently, it stopped syncing with a server error.  Unfortunately, I see NO WAY to modify (or even view) the SMTP settings.  If you go to account settings and click "Change" on the gmail account, you are presented with this dialog:

[image]

Clicking next just says "Account successfully updated!".  Clicking "Reset settings" does what you would expect (nothing, if you have defaults).

What am I missing? How do I view and change the IMAP and SMTP settings?  Server, port, password, etc...

Answer (score 1):

There is a separate entry for "Server settings" in the accounts dropdown.

[image]

This provides what I want. Not sure how I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: Repair Account**

1. Go to File > Account Settings > Account Settings.
2. Select your account and choose Repair.
3. Expand the Advanced options and select “Let me repair my account manually”.
4. Click Repair.

**Options 2: Mail in Control Panel**

1. Open Control Panel > Mail > Show Profiles.
2. Select the profile which you want to change.
3. Choose Properties > Email Accounts.
4. Double Click POP/IMAP account. You will see the previous ‘Change Account’ dialog.

**Options 3: Send/Receive Settings**

1. Click Send/Receive tab > Send/Receive groups > Define Send/Receive groups.
2. Click Edit.
3. Select the account you want to change and click “Account Properties..”

Check this thread: [Can't Access My Email Account Settings](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3b6bf67a-1d2f-457b-846c-ddc184fcacaf/cant-access-my-email-account-settings?forum=outlook)